# Android sdk и eclipse

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

Устанавливал Android SDK по инструкции которую нашел [здесь](http://itblog.name/archives/678), и при обновлении Android SDK, Eclipse мне выдает окно с надписью :

> location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences

В Google советуют установить переменную в windows, с полным путем к папке tools, только не помогает нифига... Все равно выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем разобрался сам :)
Кому интересно, то в самом eclips'e переходите в Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location and setup SDK path